# How do you unlock "Classic" difficulty mode?

Tags: the-evil-within-2

In The Evil Within 2, the hardest difficulty mode is "Classic" and is not available from the very start.

How do you unlock this difficulty mode?

---

Note that I would assume it is unlocked by completing the game, but in the original game you unlocked "Akumu" (the hardest difficulty) by completing the game on "Survival" or above ("Casual" did not unlock it).

So I am particularly interested to know if "Classic" can be unlocked by completing "Casual", or if "Survival" is required? That is of course assuming it's completing the game that actually unlocks this mode, and not something different.

Comment: Not sure if people can answer you this until game actually releases.

Comment: @lentinant: There seems to be plenty of people who are playing it already. Whether that is people who work for companies that get it early (game reviews for example) or regular people who have just got their pre-orders delivered already. In fact, I think it's already been released in some countries. I certainly don't have access to it yet, but I was hoping to get an answer before I start playing it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to unlock Classic mode, just beat the game on any difficulty. [Source](http://www.gamerevolution.com/guides/351557-evil-within-2-classic-mode-unlock-hardest-difficulty):

> To unlock Classic Difficulty, you have to beat the game once on any difficulty.

Comment: Yeah there seems to be plenty of sources around now to confirm that this is correct.